# try/except doesn't catch TypeError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, typeerror, try-except

I'm quite new at Python, so forgive me if my question is silly, however, I cannot understand what's the difference between two functions below and why the second one works when exception is used and the fist one doesn't. I tried swapping 'result' with 'return' but it doesn't help. 
I was thinking that my condition for missing argument is incorrect but even if I remove it and leave only *return 'month missing'*, the exception is still not printed.

Thanks for your help.

```
def after_n_months(year, month):
    try:
        result year + (month // 12) 
    except TypeError:
        return 'month missing' if month is None else 'year missing' 
print(after_n_months( 2000, ))


def divide(x, y):
    try:
        result = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "division by zero!"
print(divide(2,0))
```

Comment: It should be`return year + (month // 12)`

Comment: Can you post the actual error? You should get a syntax error because of `result`. After that, you should get a TypeError when calling the first function. Its because 2 positional arguments are required and this happens before the function is called and so the function's exception handler is not envolved.

Comment: One positional argument is missing, to test the exception you should run it with: print(after_n_months( 2000, None))

Answer (score 1):

It's because TypeError exception is catch before you enter in the function.

Try this instead

```
def after_n_months(year, month):
    return year + (month // 12) 

try : 
    print(after_n_months(2000))
except:
    print("error")
```

EDIT :
To test your function you can also put into None

```
def after_n_months(year, month):
    try:
        return year + (month // 12) 
    except TypeError:
        return 'month missing' if month is None else 'year missing' 
    print(after_n_months( 2000 ))

print(after_n_months(2000, None))
print(after_n_months(None, 12))
```

EDIT2:
You can also put your function inputs in None, like this and remove the expections, because it's not needed.

```
def after_n_months(year = None, month = None):
        if year is None:
            print("Year missing")
            return None
        if month is None:
            print("Month is missing")
            return None
        return year + (month // 12) 

after_n_months(5,12)
after_n_months(year=5)
after_n_months(month=12)
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions. They are helpful, however, what I'm trying to achieve is   to avoid `TypeError: after_n_months() missing 1 required positional argument: 'month'` in case one of the arguments is actually missing. Your suggestion does work if None is typed as one of the arguments, however, what if one argument is actually missing (only year or only month is given). Whenever I try this, TypeError is always returned..

Comment: If you want to see if one element is missing you can do ```def after_n_months(year=None, month=None)``` And add a condition ```if month is None:``` ```if year is None:```